# Python Circular Import - Works locally but not on server

Tags: python, importerror

**Background Information**

- Python 2.7.1 (r271:86832) on server and locally
- Using virtualenv with all dependencies the same
- Local Python is 64 bit
- Server Python is 32 bit
- Using Django

**Actual Problem**

We hit a circular import problem on our server that wasn't caught during any testing.

Doing a trivial circular import example shows that circular imports are indeed erroring locally.

We stuck some prints at the top of each file as it gets imported.

Local behaviour:

```
priority.__init__.py
sync.tasks.keywords.py
priority.reasons.py
priority.__init__.py (<- circular import but it works??)
priority.reasons.py
```

Server behaviour:

```
priority.__init__.py
sync.tasks.keywords.py
priority.__init__.py (<- circular import but it works??)
Traceback (most recent call last):
    ...
    from sync.tasks.keywords import check_keywords
    ImportError: cannot import name check_keywords
```

I'm completely baffled. Code is exactly the same. I'm double baffled by the fact that the import chain is slightly different before erroring as well.

So... any tips on where to start looking?

Comment: Try running with `python -v`. Double check that the modules are loaded from where you think they should be

Comment: No compiled `*.pyc` files hanging around somewhere that cause a different import order?

Comment: As @evert mentions: remove all .pyc and .pyo on dev and server. Bit me quite some times...

Comment: @Evert binned all the pyc already :( python -v is a good shout... will try and see where I get

Comment: Any chance you can run it through `pdb` on both machines, and step through (into) the import statements? Though I guess `python -v` will show most of that anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to just break the circular import by moving one of the imports inside your classes/functions (instead of the top of the file). In my opinion this method doesn't have any serious drawbacks and saves quite a lot of time of hard and pretty useless debugging of the circular imports.